# How can I trigger the same option again?

Tags: jquery, select, onclick, onchange

Is there a way to trigger the same option once again and get an alert:

```js
  $(document).on('change', '.item-select', function() {
    
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    alert(optionValue);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <select class="item-select">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I want to click on `Saab` and get an alert `Saab` and then immediately click on `Saab` again and get an alert.

Comment: You want to alert if you click on option already selected?

Comment: That's just going to create an endless loop?  Unless you want to specify a max number of clicks/alerts.

Comment: Yes I do not use the option box to select something. I just want, that it alerts the name I click. And I have to be able to click the same name again and get the same alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a blank value and reset the select which won't trigger the `change` event.

I think you've already asked [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256159/how-can-i-add-a-row-via-select-box-to-datatable).

```js
$(document).on('change', '.item-select', function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  $('option', this).first().prop('selected', true)
  alert(optionValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="item-select">
  <option>Select make...</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This isn't always possible depending on the UI requirements. Plus it's not required as it's possible to do what the OP needs without adding redundant options. See the duplicates for more details.

Comment: I understand that. But the OP hasn't ruled it out considering the link to the same question in my answer gives more clarity on what the OP is trying to achieve.